# ref to a hash -> its member array -> this array's member's value. How to elegantly access and test?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

I want to use an expression like

```
@{ %$hashref{'key_name'}[1]
```

or

```
%$hashref{'key_name}->[1]
```

to get - and then test - the second (index = 1) member of an array (reference) held by my hash as its "key_name" 's value. But, I can not.

This code here is correct (it works), but I would have liked to combine the two lines that I have marked into one single, efficient, perl-elegant line.

```
foreach  my $tag  ('doit', 'source', 'dest' ) {
    my $exists = exists( $$thisSectionConfig{$tag}); 
    my @tempA = %$thisSectionConfig{$tag} ;          #this line
    my $non0len = (@tempA[1] =~ /\w+/ );             # and this line
    if ( !$exists || !$non0len) {
        print STDERR "No complete \"$tag\" ... etc ... \n";
        # program exit ...
    }
```

I know you (the general 'you') can elegantly combine these two lines. Could someone tell me how I could do this?

This code it testing a section of a config file that has been read into a $thisSectionConfig reference-to-a-hash by Config::Simple. Each config file key=value pair then is (I looked with datadumper) held as a two-member array: [0] is the key, [1] is the value. The $tag 's are configuration settings that must be present in the config file sections being processed by this code snippet.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [`Arrow operator(->)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator). I guess you want something like this:

```
foreach  my $tag  ('doit', 'source', 'dest') {
    if(exists $thisSectionConfig -> {$tag}){ 
        my $non0len = ($thisSectionConfig -> {$tag} -> [1] =~ /(\w+)/) ;         
    }            
    else {
        print STDERR "No complete \"$tag\" ... etc ... \n";
        # program exit ...
    }
```